# Loop to calculate Zscore of each cells of a range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, statistics

Got a column of 2y historical volatility values (B) that changes every day in length. I'm importing the past 2 years business days so that range can change from one day to another.
I would like to calculate the zscore for each cells and write it in the related C cell (B7 vol, C7 zscore, B8 vol, C8 zscore etc...)
I wrote the code to do it on the last vol and write it on the last C cell which is cool but I'm now trying to write a loop and fill my whole C column with each zscore.
I'm not of a very high level in VBA (I find code and mod it basically), found a loop for stocks LN returns but I'm struggling to be honest.

What would be the easiest loop to use, knowing that I need to loop the last vol selection and the zscore writing, the selection of the whole range doesn't change.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Zscore1()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Zscore As Double
Dim Lastvol As Double
Dim Vols As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("2Y Data Import")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("B7")

'Select Vols
  sht.Range(StartCell, StartCell.End(xlDown)).Select
  Set Vols = Selection
'Select Lastvol
  sht.Range("B7").Select
  Selection.End(xlDown).Select
  Lastvol = Selection.Value
'Calculate Zscore & Write Result
  sht.Range("B7").Select
  Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Value = (Lastvol - 
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Vols)) / 
  Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(Vols)

End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of an example with only one column of vols.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBcZI.jpg)

Column A Dates, Column B vols, Column C where I'd like to calculate my zscore with vba, Column D zscore calculated with the following formula:

```
Function Zscore(Lastvol As Double, Vols As Range) As Double

Zscore = (Lastvol - Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Vols)) / 
Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(Vols)

End Function
```

Next step will be to do that on 294 columns. (Dates in A, 294 vols from B to KI, corresponding zscores from KJ to VQ) But I think I can do that.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Think you might need to attach a screenshot.

Comment: I don't think you need VBA for this. You should be able to do this with just formulas. Saying that, if you can provide a screenshot of your sheet (as @SJR mentioned) it will help to make things more clear

Comment: Ah, to be fair got 200+ columns of vols and the next step will be to do a loop to do that on all the columns, that's why I'm using vba. Let me try to upload a screenshot

Comment: I still don't really understand this. What do you need to do in C that you haven't already done in D and why do you need VBA if you already have a formula?

Comment: Sorry for not giving all the info, I'm importing only the business days, otherwise my average will be wrong with week days (value will be carry over and will be there twice) . So basically my range of data in A (dates) and B (vols) will be different every day potentially hence the .End(xlDown), so my zscore range will be different as well, then the number of columns will be fixed so that should be alright, but the problem is the dynamic range of dates and values imported

Comment: So will need to clear the range where I put all my zscores before hand every time the workbook is open, and thats why im trying to do a loop that will end when the next cell IsEmpty I believe

Comment: Would you kindly reveal the `Excel` formula that you are using in column `D`. When you say *200+ columns*, do you possibly mean rows? If not, could you clarify where they are.

Comment: Hi I've put the formula in my post as we are limited in the comments. but it should give the same result as the last lines in my sub. So far I have a dynamic number of rows and doing this example on one column but will have 294 columns of vols from B to KI with dates in A. Then will calculate the zscores from KJ to VQ.

Comment: but if it can be done with fomulas I'm open, just don't see how to deal with the dynamic range of rows, that I use to calculate the average that enters into the zscore calculation

Comment: No one? Thanks a lot